# Make dropdown list items visible based on permissions

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I have a drop down list that populates with our SPgroups. I am creating a web part where users can go in and create/edit/delete sp groups. I want the groups in the drop down list to only be visible by owners of that group. Below is what I have been messing around with but it is not working. Any thoughts would be appreciated.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{         

       if (!Page.IsPostBack)
  {

    SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;            
    string groupName = null;
    SPGroupCollection groups = null;
    groups = web.SiteGroups;
    DropDownList2.Items.Clear();
    DropDownList1.Items.Clear();
    foreach (SPGroup group in groups)
    {
        if (group.Owner == web.CurrentUser)
        {
            groupName = group.Name;
            DropDownList2.Items.Add(groupName);
            DropDownList1.Items.Add(groupName);
        }
    }

  }

}
```